# NavigateUrl with RouteUrl from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, url-routing

In `asp.net web forms`. I have a repeater with a hyperlink and a hidden field. I'm trying to set the `NavigateUrl` on databind for the repeater with the value of the hidden field.

Here's what I've got:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HyperLink hyperLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HyperLink1");
        HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1");
        hyperLink.NavigateUrl = "<%$RouteUrl:id=" + hf.Value.ToString() + " %>";
    }
}
```

Problem is that what I end up with is this url

```
http://localhost:49333/Video/skate/%3C%$RouteUrl:sport=skate,category=flat,id=5716c22e89f9d719bc1b2f6f%20%%3E.
```

I'm probably misunderstanding this but couldn't find any info on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this answer is already all over here but I didn't realize it applied to me

```
NavigateUrl=<%# Eval("id", "~/webpages/VideoEmbed.aspx?id={0}")
```